# JavaScript: Variable inside function is not accessible. Please explain behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have following code snippet to be executed,

```
function OuterFn(){
        var slices = 0; // variable inside Outer function
        this.getSlices = function(){
            return slices;
        }
        this.slice = function(){
            slices++;
        }
    }
    var outerFn = new OuterFn();
    console.log(outerFn.getSlices());
    console.log(outerFn.slices); // print outer function variable
```

Why output of this code is:
**0 

undefined**

Comment: It's called closures. You cannot access the inner variable unless you return it or assign it to a global one. This is the main concept of it. Private variables.

Comment: I am confused about your comment _"print outer function"_, what is that ?

Comment: Slices is a variable defined inside the function's scope. It only exists in the function's closure (I recommend you [https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures] to better understand it).

OuterFn()'s *this* object, in your example, references to the newly created object outerFn (or whatever other new objects you create using `new OuterFn()`). For more about *this*, see [https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes]

Comment: @Rayon my mistake. Edited.

Comment: @Rayon Both links are 404 :(

Comment: You need to `return{ getSlices: getSlices, slice: slice }` from your function to make `
    console.log(outerFn.getSlices()); work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I don't think this is a duplicate question. One you linked simply ask about how to dynamically access variables (actually object properties, attending to accepted answer) which, in the provided example, happen to be in a closure. I think more that the title of the other question is badly selected... ;-)

Comment: @Syntac Sorry but I don't want correction I want to understand why and how it works. I'm trying to study Closures, thought someone can explain me better here.

Comment: if you have access to chat, we can chat about it and i will try my best to explain it.

Comment: Im in the room now, as you are, but you seem not to notice

Comment: @Syntac My reputation is lower than the required to join the chat. Sorry to make you wait.

Comment: No problem, can you join [this](https://join.skype.com/ai2twjNN0iJK)?

Comment: @Syntac thank you very much for your valuable time :)